# how to start loop from top with condition result inside and skip other part

Tags: python-3.x

I have in cycle, while True with different codes inside. if  I have "x" in line of text file, how skip PART 2 and start cycle from beginning, but if not "x"  I want pass PART 2

how to do it in this case, can you show me please exactly with this code:

```
import time

loop = 1

while True:

    try:

        print ('PART 1')

        text = open('D:\my_path\text.txt', "r")
        searchlines = text.readlines()
        for z, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            if ('y') in line:
                for l in searchlines:
                    print (z, line,' if "y" go to top, skip PART 2')
                    time.sleep(1)
                    break
            if not ('y') in line: #not sure about "if not" if needed here
                print (z, line,'not "y" pass PART 2')
                time.sleep(1)
                break
        continue
    except ValueError:
        print ("Could not convert data to an integer.")


    try:

        print ('PART 2')

    except ValueError:
        print ("Could not convert data to an integer.")

    loop += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

looks like result "y" but no, just continue inside of cycle:

```
PART 1
0 y  if "y" go to top, skip PART 2'
PART 1
0 y  if "y" go to top, skip PART 2'
```

bad result, now without y:

```
PART 1
0 k if not "y" pass PART 2
PART 1
0 k if not "y" pass PART 2
```

other way with continue inside for, but same wrong results with "y" in text file:

```
PART 1
0 y  if "y" go to top, skip PART 2
PART 2
```

and without "y" in text file:

```
PART 1
PART 2
```

Comment: Your second `try` block is a bug. The `continue` in the fist block is misplaced. It should be immediately next to the statement after which you want to start from the beginning of next iteration.

Comment: could you show me please how can I get the required result in this code if somehow is possible, or how to change it but keep same possibilities in cycle with  **while True** inside with **try** parts

Comment: put `continue` after `break` in 1st `if`, after breaking out.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ('y') in line:
    for l in searchlines:
        print (z, line,' if "y" go to top, skip PART 2')
        time.sleep(1)
        break
    continue  # <- add here
if not ('y') in line: #not sure about "if not" if needed here
    print (z, line,'not "y" pass PART 2')
    time.sleep(1)
    break
# continue -> delete this
```

Though I have doubts about if this is the best way to go for whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: ok, but not sure if it works in this case, maybe I'm doing something wrong, I've added  results above... i need something like `goto` maybe, but have problem with install on windows 10 64bit python 3.5

Comment: @krankron if you need goto you may want to rethink your code design. Goto is almost always wrong.

Comment: @krankron if there are bugs, then they could be weeded out. But the semantics of the overall code/ pseudo-code must be concrete. From there follows the actual code. I am not aware of a situation that will warrant the use of `goto` in the face of all the constructs available in Python. If you still thing you need `goto` either you are doing it wrong or you are doing it in a wrong language.

Comment: ok I understand that the code can be different and better, anyway the only thing i want get here is, if I have "y" in first condition, skip PART 2, star this loop from beginning, if I have no "y" in first condition pass PART 2 and back to loop naturally. about second "if not" condition I not sure if needed, because first means same, if "y" was it was, if not pass PART 2 but important is how to do it exactly in this construction if there is the way  to do it

Comment: I have no idea what the inner `for` loop is for in the 1st try block. You are iterating over a list for each item in the list?

Comment: yes if file contains other characters, search for line "y" and then I need if "y" exist  skip PART 2, start from top, but if there is no, pass everything. yes without try it is just simple condition, but the question is if I want do this exactly this way in this case

Comment: `"y"` is supposed to be in certain lines or somewhere in the file?

Comment: in file for example: `> other1 > other2 > y > other3 >...` so here "y" exist. in code simply said `if ('y') in line:` if this character is exist in the text file find it and give me desired result 1, if not, give me desired result 2

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a big re-write on this, making use of functions to separate out part 1 and part 2. That way you can make use of nesting to determine if you should do part 2 or not. It keeps your code for the parts separate too.

```
import time

loop = 1
text = open('text.txt', "r")
searchlines = text.readlines()  # Pull the file out of the loop, only load once.

def part_1(): # Keep part 1 & 2 in functions, easier to maintain.
    try:
        print ('PART 1')
        for z, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            got_y = 'y' in line
            if got_y:
                print (z, line,' if "y" go to top, skip PART 2')
                # Do whatever you need to do if there is a y in part 1
            else:
                print (z, line,'not "y" execute PART 2')
                # Do whatever you need to do if there is NO y in part 1
            time.sleep(1)
            yield not got_y, line  # Generator function, so Part 2 will be considered after each line
    except ValueError:
        print ("Could not convert data to an integer.")

def part_2(line):
    try:
        print ('PART 2')
        # Part 2 code goes here
        print(line)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Could not convert data to an integer.")

while True:      
    for needs_part_2, line in part_1():  # Iterate through generator (1 item at a time)
        if needs_part_2:  # Boolean describes if we need to do part 2 or not.
            part_2(line)  # Needs to be nested, but function seperates code.

    loop += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: yes works perfect, but code  different now, so seems is not possible exactly with my example...

Comment: Then I'd need more information to go on. Are you passing variables from part 1 to part 2? Is that why it's not working? It should be fixable, I'll add passing the line into part 2 in the answer.

Comment: well I think your code is more then enough, other thing is another question maybe you have some advice about it, because if i going to use something between parts like variables it is words, my question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453917/unique-number-for-line-in-text-file

Comment: I followed the hyper-link but got page not found.

Comment: here is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486649/how-to-sort-words-in-sequence-in-which-they-were-written-and-call-next-or-previo